# iOS Tweet compose issue

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

Previously i installed TwitterKit through Fabric. Now i have upgrade it to 3.0.1, Now i am facing problem with composing tweet.

This is my code:

```
let composer = TWTRComposer()

composer.setText("just setting up my Twitter Kit")
composer.setImage(UIImage(named: "twitterkit"))

// Called from a UIViewController
composer.show(from: self.navigationController!) { (result in
    if (result == .done) {
        print("Successfully composed Tweet")
    } else {
        print("Cancelled composing")
    }
}
```

and i am getting following error:

[TwitterKit] did encounter error with message "Error obtaining user auth token.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain Code=-1 "

Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'
/oauth/request_token

" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=

Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'
/oauth/request_token

}

I have already login in my twitter app in my device. When i checking with following condition it always return to else block.

```
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore hasLoggedInUsers]) {

} else {

}
```

My requirement is compose tweet from my app. if the user have twitter account in their device otherwise it will ask user to login .

Comment: Did you ever solve this?